# Remove dynamically created button's history - jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

this is my first entry on StackOverFlow.
I'm working on a project and it needs jQuery to perform a master/detail table layout.
I have to work in asp.net C#, master and detail table generate dynamically.
So what is my problem:
I generate the master table with ajax:

```
        function refreshMasterTable() {
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "tablefunctions.aspx?mode=showmastertable",
            success: function (html) {
                $("#tbl_master").html(html);
                prevAjaxReturned = true;
                $('input[type=button]').click(function () {
                    var bid, trid;
                    bid = (this.id);
                    trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                    if ($("#detail_" + trid).length == 0) {
                        detailShow = true;
                        pointer = $(this).closest('tr');
                        pointer.after("<tr><td colspan=5><div id=detail_" + trid + "></div></td></tr>");
                        $.get("tablefunctions.aspx?mode=showdetailtable&id=" + trid, function (response) {
                            $('#detail_' + trid).html(response);
                        });
                        $(document).on('click', '#submitMasterData', function () {
                            value = $('#name').val();
                            $.get("tablefunctions.aspx?mode=mastertableupdate&id=" + trid + "&name=" + value);
                            refreshMasterTable();
                        });
                    } else {
                        detailShow = false;
                        $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

In tablefunctions.aspx there is an entry, what generates the submit button:

```
html.Append("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitMasterData\" /></td></tr>");
```

So the problem begins here. Each time when I ask a new detail row in the master table, a new `submitMasterData` instance of button creates and the `$(document).on('click', '#submitMasterData', function ()` event triggers on every previous values. If I reload the page, the first detail request is OK, but the "collection" begins again.
`$("#submitMasterData").remove();` didn't solve the problem. Sorry for my bad English, if something is not clear, please ask me...

Comment: If I read you right, $('input[type=button]') is scoped to every button on the page so each time you add a new detail you are adding a new click event to all the buttons. Do you need to scope down the button?

Comment: If the issue is with elements generated with the same id, you can simply replace the event handler on the class instead of id , $(document).on('click', '.submitMasterData', function () {

Comment: Hi! I changed the line in aspx: html.Append("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"submitMasterData\" /></td></tr>"); In jQuery script, I made $(document).on('click', '.submitMasterData', function (). But the problem is the same. First click is OK, on second click I receive the first click's id, then the id what I clicked twice. On 3rd click I receive 1st, than 2nd and then the 3rd click's id....and so on...

Comment: Bindrin, you were right. $(document).off('click', '.submitMasterData'); solved my problem. After I process the event, I remove the event from the button. :)

Comment: @DinoMyte elements should not be generated with the same IDs, that would be producing invalid HTML.

Comment: @AdamKonieska : that's exactly what i said, OP should replace it with class instead of id

Comment: @hbbst can you share the HTML that you're generating please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `$(document).on()` function is binding a new event each time a button is clicked *without* removing any of the previous events.  You can use the `off()` function to remove the old ones in queue.

```
function refreshMasterTable() {
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "tablefunctions.aspx?mode=showmastertable",
        success: function (html) {
            $("#tbl_master").html(html);
            prevAjaxReturned = true;
            $('input[type=button]').click(function () {
                var bid, trid;
                bid = (this.id);
                trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                if ($("#detail_" + trid).length == 0) {
                    detailShow = true;
                    pointer = $(this).closest('tr');
                    pointer.after("<tr><td colspan=5><div id=detail_" + trid + "></div></td></tr>");
                    $.get("tablefunctions.aspx?mode=showdetailtable&id=" + trid, function (response) {
                        $('#detail_' + trid).html(response);
                    });
                    //need to unbind all the previously attached events
                    $(document).off('click', '#submitMasterData');
                    $(document).on('click', '#submitMasterData', function () {
                        value = $('#name').val();
                        $.get("tablefunctions.aspx?mode=mastertableupdate&id=" + trid + "&name=" + value);
                        refreshMasterTable();
                    });
                } else {
                    detailShow = false;
                    $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

You can view a proof of concept in this JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfc6wzt8/

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Yes, as I said before, it solved the problem. :) Just a little thing... How can I remove the button from DOM, not just remove the event from the button? $('#submitMasterData).remove(); didn't work.

Comment: If you have it exactly as you typed in your comment, `$('#submitMasterData).remove();` is missing a closing quote and should be `$('#submitMasterData').remove();` instead.  You can see an example in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/x3sk04rd/